# Translate to Blade+Laravel a while loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This code works, however in my learning of Laravel, I want to know if using Blade+Laravel syntax, can be better implemented

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= (5 - $post->images->count())) {
        echo '<div class="col"> </div>';
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is. Templating is made just for that, you can see how similar things are done with the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops

Comment: I see nothing Laravel or Blade related in your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops

I would suggest using a for loop instead of a while loop in this case:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= (5 - $post->images->count()); $i++)
    <div class="col"> </div>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure is the best way to do, but works.

```php
<?php $z = 0; ?>
@while ($z < 3)
  {{ "test".$z }} 
  <?php $z++ ?>
@endwhile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@php 
    $i = 0; 
@endphp 
@while (++$i <= (5 - $post->images->count())) 
    <div class="col"> 
    </div>
@endwhile
```

Comment: Consider adding any comment, description, explanation... to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Templating is made just for that, you can see how similar things are done with the docs : [laravel blade : loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops)

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <  $post->images->count()); $i++)
    <div class="col"> </div>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <= (5 - $post->images->count()); $i++) 
   <div class="col"> </div>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to use @foreach

```
@foreach( $image as $post->images )

   <div class="col"> </div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case *beacause you are looping count()* you should use foreach, however you may also  be interested @forelse:

```
@forelse($image as $img)
<div class="col"> {{ $img }}</div>
@empty 
<div class="col"> NO IMAGES </div>
@endforesle
```